# Python - Using Fabric with Sudo

Tags: python, linux, bash, backup, fabric

I'm pretty new to python and fabric and I am trying to do a simple code where I can get the output on two hosts that uses sudo, although I keep getting an error.... Can anyone help me out with what I might be missing ?

My code:

```
from fabric.api import *
from getpass import getpass
from fabric.decorators import runs_once
env.hosts = ['host1','host2'] 
env.port = '22'
env.user = 'username' 
env.password="password"


def sudo_dsmc(cmd):
    sudo("-l")
```

When I run: `fab sudo_dsmc:"-1"` :

```
MacBookPRO:PYTHON username$ fab sudo_dsmc:"-l"
[host1] Executing task 'sudo_dsmc'
[host1] sudo: -l
[host1] out: sudo password:
[host1] out: Sorry, user username is not allowed to execute '/bin/bash -l -c -  l' as root on host1.
[host1] out: 

Fatal error: sudo() received nonzero return code 1 while executing!

Requested: -l
Executed: sudo -S -p 'sudo password:'  /bin/bash -l -c "-l"

Aborting.
Disconnecting from host1... done.
```

Although I can run the apt-get update with my below function fine without any errors:

```
def sudo_command(cmd):
    sudo("apt-get update")    
# run like: fab sudo_command:"apt-get-update"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your sudoers file is preventing you from running that command as sudo. Check your /etc/sudoers file and read the sudo documentation.

Also "-l" isn't a valid command. sudo takes -l as an optional flag (which lists commands allowed by the user). But Fabric's sudo appears to be taking unknown strings and routing them through /bin/bash instead of using them directly as sudo command parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the response, i noticed that when i use: run("sudo -l") instead of sudo("-l") it does work. Although, it ends up prompting for the password. Although, it prompt for the password before it outputs for each host. Do you know if theres anyway to use run("sudo -l") with having it prompt for the password?

Comment: You can set-up passwordless logins using ssh keys. Google for "ssh passwordless login" and you will find many pages detailing how to configure this.